# Http.BeginForm does not post

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have spent about 3 hours trying to figure out why this view is not posting. It is probably a really dumb mistake. When I click on my submit button absolutely nothing happens. I have several submit forms completed already but this one just does not want to work!

This is my cshtml file

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "ZipCodeUtility";
}

<h2>ZipCodeUtility</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetZipsByDistance", "Dev", FormMethod.Post))
{
<span>Find zip codes within "x" miles from me</span>
<br />
@Html.TextBox("DistanceMiles")

<input type="button" value="GetZipsByDistance" />
}
```

And here is my controller action

```
public ActionResult GetZipsByDistance(string DistanceMiles)
    {
        FileStream zipFile = new FileStream("~/StaticData/2013_Gaz-zcta_national.txt", FileMode.Open);

        Utility.ZipCodeUtility.ZipCodes zips = Utility.ZipCodeUtility.ZipCodeReader.ReadZipCodes(zipFile);

        var closeCodes = zips.FindLessThanDistance(zips[46324], double.Parse(DistanceMiles));

        ViewBag.Codes = closeCodes;

        return View(new ViewModels.ViewModelBase());
    }
```

I have tried comparing this view and controller with many of my others that do work and everything seems legit. I tried viewing the source in chrome to see if there was something funky going on but there doesnt seem to be either. If I hover over the button the browser does not display the url either..

Comment: Where is your submit button? You have just usual button

Comment: Ah!!!! That was the problem! I wrote "button" in the type instead of "Submit" lol. Dumb mistake as usual. Thanks Sergey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the input type:

```
<input type="submit" value="GetZipsByDistance" />
```

A regular button will not post the form.

Comment: Thank you Ufuk, that part of the form slipped my eye.